# xsl:for-each giving constraint

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I have one question regarding xsl:for-each

if there are list of code

COMPXXXX
COMPXXXX
COMPXXXX
LAWSXXXX
LAWSXXXX

XXXX (are numbers 2383)

and if I just want to display code that starts with COMP,

how should I do this??

I tried to have xsi:course[code='COMP'] but it did not work (of course I guess..)

```
        <xsl:for-each select="xsi:catalogue/xsi:course[code='COMP']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:code" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:title" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:year" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:science" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:area" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:subject" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:updated" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:unit" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:description" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:outcomes" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:incompatibility" />
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
xsi:catalogue/xsi:course[starts-with(code,'COMP')]
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the standard XPath function **[`starts-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with)**

Comment: hi it returns the following error:XPath error : Invalid number of arguments
xmlXPathCompiledEval: 2 objects left on the stack.
runtime error: file courses.xsl line 14 element for-each
Failed to evaluate the 'select' expression.

Comment: @JaneDoe, There is no problem in the XPath expression -- the error is in the code you haven't shown to us. In case you edit the question and provide a complete (but small) source XML document, many people will be able to evaluate this expression against the document and to get the wanted elements selected -- this is a simple exercise.

Comment: basically, my xml and xsd and xsl validates perfectly without this starts-with. It seems that code='COMP' is incorrect because according to the URL you have given, it must have two arguments (string, string) and if it have starts-with(code='COMP'), it is not having two arguments. Isn't this why it returns an error?

Comment: the pertinent XML is just this <course> <code> COMPXXXX </code> </course>

Comment: @JaneDoe, But this contradicts your code -- I don't see any namespaces declared and used here -- at all.

Comment: @JaneDoe, Ooopss ... Yes, this was an error -- fixed now. Please, try it.